# Run Javascript update before asp button postback and access updated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm looking to populate a hidden field once a button is clicked via javascript but also post back and access the hidden field in the code behind from the same button click.

The context is a user will enter a postcode and radius, click the search button, I then use the Google API to get the lat and lng of the postcode and populate hidden fields with these values, the search button then performs the search and populates the results which I'm currently trying to handle with the standard asp:button onclick event

Here is my JS code

```
    var geocoder;
    function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }

    function codeAddress() {
      var address = $('#PostcodeTextBox').val();
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              $('#Latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
              $('#Longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());

              __doPostBack($('#SearchButton').attr('id'), '');
          } else {
              alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And my markup

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Longitude" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="Latitude" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<legend><h3>Supplier Search</h3></legend>
<label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Supplier Type</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="SupplierTypeDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
  <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<label class="control-label" for="PostcodeTextBox">Postcode</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="PostcodeTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Postcode" />
<label class="control-label" for="RadiusDropDownList">Radius</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="RadiusDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
  <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="20" Value="20" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="50" Value="50" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-large" OnClientClick="codeAddress();" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

backend code

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SearchInfo search = new SearchInfo ();
search.Lat = Latitude.Value; // empty
search.Lng = Longitude.Value; // empty
}
```

This has gone through many diffrent versions based on comments online, the problem is each time I hit SearchButton_Click the hidden fields have a blank value

Any help or ideas would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a really easy solution to this, but I can't think of it, so I'll give you my "hack".

Use CSS to hide your .Net button

```
#SearchButton { display: none }
```

Add another dummy button in .Net (or standard HTML)

```
<button type="button" id="fake-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Search</button>
```

And then some jQuery:

```
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = $('#PostcodeTextBox').val();
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          $('#Latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
          $('#Longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());

          //alert($('#Latitude').val());
          //alert($('#Longitude').val());

          $('#SearchButton').click(); //trigger the click event of the submit button
      } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fake-button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // populate your hidden fields here
        codeAddress();
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I still have the same issue of the hidden fields populated by JS are empty on the Search Button click event. If I press search button again the values are there.

Comment: @LEEMANDEVILLE I updated the code sample to be more complete. You couple uncoment the `//alert` lines to see if the hidden fields have been populated before the submit is made.

Comment: Hi again,  sorry I might not have been clear in my explanation. I can see and as in your example that the hidden fields are populated by the JS but in the code behind the submit in the button click event the values are not there. If I then submit again the values can be obtained in the code behind.

Comment: I'd need to see your C# code, are you sure the value of the hidden field is not reset on Page_Load or something else interfering with it? Where do you handle the Postback, on Page_Load or ButtonClick event in code behind?

Comment: Hi, I have added to the original post